# Android: Integrating Kotlin with Dagger and Protobuf

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, grpc, kapt

I have existing project that builds successfully with Java, [gRPC](https://grpc.io/)(Protobuf) and Dagger2. I want to add Kotlin to the project.

I have converted data files to Kotlin quite easily. When I converted first activity (containing Dagger2) build failed. After adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and pressing Sync Now it says

```
Folder C:\AndroidStudioProjects\Bingo\app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\debug


Folder C:\AndroidStudioProjects\Bingo\app\build\generated\source\kaptKotlin\release


3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

The build still fails, now it doesn't recognize files generated by protobuf also.

Has anyone tried Kotlin, Dagger, Protobuf together? I don't want to completely replace Java with Kotlin.

This is my module level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.productions.bingo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.4.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.8.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    // Options added to --grpc_out
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Inform IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse or NetBeans about the generated code.
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/javalite"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    // Support Libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    // gRPC
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.11.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.11.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.11.0'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'

    //Dagger
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13"

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    // Celebration
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.2.0'

    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Kotlin libraries
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5"
}
```

This is my project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this to my app level gradle file in android closure.

```
sourceSets {
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/debug/java'
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/debug/grpc'
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/debug/javalite'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/release/java'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/release/grpc'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/release/javalite'
        main.proto.srcDirs += 'src/main/proto'
        main.kotlin.srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto'
    }
```

Comment: Does "3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause" warning matter ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. :)

Comment: You'll need to remove debug.java... to generate signed APKs